# Error while exporting to Excel with named sheets

Tags: export, bugs, excel

Using Mathematica v9.0.1
This example is [from the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLSX.html):

```
data1 = Table[{t, 9.8*t^2}, {t, 0, 3, .1}];
data2 = Table[{t, 9.8*t^2}, {t, 0, 5, .2}];
Export["datasets.xlsx", "Sheets" -> {"Experiment 1" -> data1, 
                                     "Experiment 2" -> data2}, "Rules"]
```

Returns:

> JLink`Java::argxs: The static method System`Convert`ExcelDump`write was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The arguments, shown here in a list, were {XLSX,C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\datasets.xlsx,{Experiment 1,Experiment 2},{{{0.,0.},{0.1,0.098},<<27>>,{2.9,82.418},{3.,88.2}},{<<1>>}},{{{Null}}},{{{}}},Author->Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com}.

While the following:

```
Export["datasets.xlsx", {data1, data2}]
```

works OK, but I need sheet names.

Any idea?

Comment: I get the same with 9.0.1 on Mac 10.8.4 . Said a few times here that I can't see why the docs can't be programmatically checked for these sorts of errors. Seems like poor QA standards.

Comment: Another example further down in the docs gives the same error. Very sloppy QA.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yep. I posted this one just because it's somewhat easier to read, but the other syntax results in the same error

Comment: Seems to work now in V10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following syntax works for exporting the two sheets:

```
data1 = Table[{t, 9.8*t^2}, {t, 0, 3, .1}];
data2 = Table[{t, 9.8*t^2}, {t, 0, 5, .2}];
Export["datasets.xlsx", {"Experiment 1" -> data1, 
  "Experiment 2" -> data2}]
```

It creates an XLSX file with two seperate sheets holding the datasets:

[image]

However, i agree with the comments above that QA for this is indeed very poor.

Comment: Great! A pity that I had to circumvent the whole thing in a hurry :(

Comment: Many thanks for that one